# How do I create a date range filter in a class based view?

Tags: python, django

#### My class based view in "views.py"

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post.objects.filter(created__range=["2020-03-09", "2020-03-31"])
    template_name = 'main/problems.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-created']
```

I have a variable "created" for when the post is created but dont know how to filter the post within a range.

Comment: Where does this `created` comes from? Is this in `request.GET`/`request.POST`?

Comment: Created comes from my Post model. `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`.model`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.model) refers to the model class, but you can specify the [**`.queryset`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.queryset):

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(created__range=['2020-03-09', '2020-03-31'])
    template_name = 'main/problems.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-created']
```